# Redraw select menu in JQuery Mobile

Tags: html, jquery-mobile

I am trying to make a JQuery Mobile select menu button **larger** by changing the `data-mini` property from `true` to `false` on the fly. I am able to change the property, but the select menu does not redraw.

It works with a button, by using `.buttonMarkup({mini: false})` (which redraws the button instantly), but as far as I know there is no equivalent for select menus.

I have tried `.selectmenu("refresh")` and `.change()` - neither redraws the select menu button.

Here is an illustration of the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/YYXuZ/

Does anyone have a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey this works for me -

```
$('#testselectmenu').parent('div').addClass('ui-fullsize');
```

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rossmartin/GcxUX/)

I noticed you won't need the `$('#testselectmenu').selectmenu('refresh');` with this approach.

/Update

To play it safe I would do this (it does the same thing while removing the data-mini attribute and ui-mini class) -

```
$('#testselectmenu').parent('div').attr('data-mini', 'false').removeClass('ui-mini').addClass('ui-fullsize');
```

I think jQM should handle this automatically when you call a `.selectmenu('refresh')`, I'm not sure why it doesn't.